# Casting string to integer gives NULL values in spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
%sql 
select int('00000282001368')
```

gives me 282001368 which is correct, when I do the same thing for below string it gives me NULL

```
%sql
select int('00012300000079')
```

gives me NULL

How to get the Integer in the second scenario?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `bigint`. Second one is not in `int` range.

```
select bigint('00012300000079')
```